# Typing individual properties in an object with generics

Tags: typescript

Given the following types:

```js
type A = {
  name: 'a';
  id: string;
};

type B = {
  name: 'b';
  url: string;
};

type C = {
  name: 'c';
  id: string;
};
```

I want to manually create an object that looks like so:

```js
{
  a: {
    pk: 'id'
  },
  b: {
    pk: 'url'
  },
  c: {
    pk: 'id'
  }
}
```

But I want it typed so that it will automatically know the allowed top level property names (the "name" value from each type) as well as possible values for `pk` (basically any property names in that type other than "name" are acceptable).

I can do it for one type like so:

```js
type ABC = A | B | C;

type MyObject<T extends ABC> = {
  [Key in T['name']]: {
    pk: keyof Omit<T, 'name'>;
  };
};

const x: MyObject<A> = {
  a: {
    pk: 'id',
  },
};
```

That type will accept *any one* of the ABC types. But I don't know how to make it so that the object can contain *all* of the ABC types.

What I want is to type "a", and then when I go to enter its "pk" value, it knows the only potential value is "id". Then I add the "b" key to the same object, and it knows the only potential "pk" value is "url".

These are just sample types, the real ones have a lot more fields and there are a lot more types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over each member of your input union, like this:

```
type MyObject<T extends { name: string }> = {
  [U in T as U['name']]: { pk: Exclude<keyof U, "name"> }
};
```

For `A | B | C`, that evaluates to:

```
type M = MyObject<A | B | C>;
/* type M = {
    a: {
        pk: "id";
    };
    b: {
        pk: "url";
    };
    c: {
        pk: "id";
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUB2BDAthAXFAORZEDcaUAlgCaEDOwATlRgOYUC+FKokUAIQTJK2PISIAjcpQCuTADYNmrDim4pe4aAGFhqdGILEAxjPS1lLdlx5b+AWRAB5SQCsIJ4AB4AKlAgAD2AIDBp6ZExcY0ZrNihOAD59SgBtAFVqDCh-LAj01KIjIgBdEsIkKDAAa0IAUUCTBVkaCG9qiBAAewAzKHSAGigAIiNh5M51Hj5oB2EnVw8vbzgAH0EodZ1EigB6ACooGag5xAN0KCwKyguLmsJh2mGKW41byWvb2-uR+QVnm4JF4XEyfL7oH6PGgA15cKD7XZAA)